# Ruby - convert string to date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to convert a string like 20170319 to a date Format, and then to day of the year.

Comment: Great, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is using [`Date::parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) and [`Date#yday`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-yday):

```
require 'date'

Date.parse("20170319").yday
#=> 78
```